# Google Map is not loading with full width in first time

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps

Google Map:

Map is not loading with full width first time when browser open it via a URL.
After refresh Map loading with full width.
I tried this in many browser.

Why and solution..
 please thanks..[image]

Comment: Have you tried delaying the loading of gmaps?

Comment: No.. if i will do this then what will happen..

Comment: Im just thinking maybe its being loaded before the layout has so not adjusting to layouts full width.

Comment: k.. welcome your suggestion.. May be this issue effeting